# Windows phone 8 GeoLocator accuracy

Tags: windows-phone-8, gps, geolocation

i'm using GeoLocator to retrieve data from the database within 10 meters, but when i use Geopostition.Coordinate.Accuracy, it gives me accuracy between 100 and 160 and never decreases, is there any way to get at least accuracy between 10,50 ? 
i'm using DesiredAccuracyInMeters and i set it to high.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on if the user is using WiFi or a cellular network, this can fluctuate wildly.

If you are using the [Geolocator Plugin for Xamarin and Windows](https://blog.xamarin.com/geolocation-for-ios-android-and-windows-made-easy/), you get this behavior for free. Just access the `DesiredAccuracy` property, which is the desired accuracy in meters.